# Why is my do..while loop not working? (prompt not executing)

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to prompt the user to enter as many numbers as they want until they hit -999 to quit. I need to check how many even numbers they entered, how many odd, the sum of the odd, the even, and their average for even and odd. I'm only a little ways into the code but I already can't get the simple loop to execute or the prompt to "prompt". The prompt is prompted by a clicking on a button and the function is attached to it.

```js
function meditation() {

  var i = parseInt(prompt("Enter an integer or (Enter -999 to quit)"), 10);

  do {

    if (i % 2) {
      document.getElementById("odd").innerHTML = i + " is odd.";
    } else if {
      document.getElementById("even").innerHTML = i + " is even.";
    }

  } while (i != -999)

}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Odd and Even Log</br>
  </h1>
</header>

<h2> Click on the button to enter the meditation numbers.</h2>
<h3>I will keep track of odd and even meditation numbers.</h3>

<button onclick="meditation()">Enter the meditation numbers.</button>
<br>

<p>The meditation numbers: </p>
</section>
```

Comment: The `prompt` isn't in your loop. So you will either never hit it or will go into an infinite loop. Also `<!--Using javascript-->` is invalid JavaScript.

Comment: `else if` should be followed by a condition, not empty space… just remove the "if".

Comment: also I don't see any `odd` or `even` ids for elements the markup.

Comment: @82Tuskers It's like the more I look over it again the more issues I see, there is also no `<body>` tag here.

Comment: @RobG Oh, okay! Thank you. So I should change the else if to just an else?

Comment: @82Tuskers Oh yeah it's pretty bare bones right now. I still have to add a lot.

Comment: @Saiba—Yes. The pattern is `if (condition) {do stuff} else {do other stuff}`. ;-)

Comment: Sorry everyone I'm quite new to javascript

Comment: @Saiba No worries. Once everything is cleaned up the primary logical issue here is the first item I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: Awesome :) it's working now.